# ¿Cómo ordenar un string que contiene numeros enteros, numeros flotantes y fracciones?

Tags: javascript, ordenamiento

Este sería el arreglo de strings desordenados, los tengo que ordenar de mayor a menor.

```
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/ 4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 6"];
```

Intenté hacer esto:

```js
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 3/8", " 1/4"];

test = test.sort((a, b) => eval(`${a} - ${b}`));
console.log(test);
```

Sé que son strings y se ordenan diferente por el unicode, pero intenté transformarlos con `Number()` y los caracteres especiales daban Nan.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que fue lo que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Yo igual, esa imagen no la veo para nada ordenada...

Comment: Intente pasarlo a numero, utilizando number pero me retorna nan con los caracteres especiales, tambien intente usando parseinty decia nan, no como ordenar con esas fracciones. Si tienes razon no esta ordenado de mayor a menor :(

Comment: Y todo lo que intentaste, con errores y todo, debe ir en la pregunta.. si no, solo parece que queres que resuelvan el ejercicio por vos.. agrega todo lo que intentaste, como texto, como tambien que errores recibiste....

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega eso a la respuesta.. tene en cuenta que si son cadenas (porque si estan entre comillas son cadenas) entonces se van a ordenar como cadenas.. no como numeros...

Comment: listo, si pero antes habia convertido con Number, pero cuando me retornaba NAN con los caracteres especiales y ahi me mente quedaba en blanco.

Comment: Calcula que los lenguajes en general (Capaz alguno si) no manejan funciones, entonces no saben que 1/2 es una funcion... tal vez tengas que hacer una funcion que las transforme? calcula que las funciones en realidad son la representacion de numeros...

Comment: Puedes intentar primero separar con str.split("/"), cada fraccion, operarlos y que queden numericos, y entonces los ordenas.

Comment: ok lo voy a intentaaar les aviso. Gracias!!

Comment: No se ve como debería quedar ordenado ://. ¿Quieres convertir los elementos a `"number"` y ordenarlos de mayor a menor?

Answer (score 5):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea ordenar de forma descendente una lista que contiene valores numéricos en una representación particular. Por ejemplo

```
valor1 = "1.1/3"
valor2 = "2"
```

Como se puede observar, los números pueden contener o no un carácter `"/"` para indicar una fracción.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución al problema es identificar el tipo de valor obtenido mediante el análisis de la cadena.

Si la cadena contiene el carácter `/` (división), podemos separar la misma en 2 mitades e intentar realizar la operación correspondiente.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let valor = "2.1/4"
let dividendo, divisor, numero;
if(valor.includes('/')) {
  dividendo = Number(valor.split('/')[0]);
  divisor = Number(valor.split('/')[1]);
  numero = dividendo / divisor;
} else {
  numero = Number(valor);
}

console.log(numero);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Teniendo esto, podemos realizar una comparación del tipo mayor / menor para ordenar los elementos.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const test = ["1/2", "3/4", "1", "1.1/ 4", "1.1/2", "2", "2.1/2", "3", "6", "4"];

const obtenerValor = valor => {
  let dividendo, divisor;
  if(valor.includes('/')) {
    dividendo = Number(valor.split('/')[0]);
    divisor = Number(valor.split('/')[1]);
    return dividendo / divisor;
  }
  return Number(valor);
}

// función para decidir el orden
const ordenDesc = (a, b) => {
  let numA = obtenerValor(a);
  let numB = obtenerValor(b);
  return numB - numA;
}

let ordenados = test.sort(ordenDesc);
console.log(ordenados);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esto ya se tiene una forma de realizar el ordenamiento de la lista recibida.

**Nota**

No se hacen comprobaciones de error. Por ejemplo, si un valor contiene "1.1/0", esto producirá un valor `Infinity`, o si el valor no puede ser convertido en un tipo `Number`, entonces se devolverá `NaN`. Habrá que tener eso en cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y esta explicación!!

Comment: Si resolvio tu problema te sugiero marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
let ordenado = test.map(item => eval(item.trim())).sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

```
//Resultado [0.275, 0.5, 0.55, 0.75, 1, 1.05, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Con "map" vamos a crear un nuevo array que contenga cada elemento del array test
"procesados" por los siguientes pasos.

1. Trim(): Lo usaremos para quitar los espacio de ambos lados de la cadena.
2. eval(): Reconocerá el string como si fuera código JS**
3. sort(): Ordena los items del array de manera ascendente.

**Considerar que la cadena que será interpretada como código no debe tener inconsistencias (como división entre cero o letras que pueda interpretar como variables sin definir) para que esto pueda funcionar

Comment: ¿Cómo se haría si se quiere conservar los strings en su estado?

Comment: Al usar el metodo map() creas un array completamente nuevo. El array original "test" mantiene la misma estructura y tipo de datos de sus elementos internos(osea sus items son tipo string).

Comment: muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo!! me ayudas muchisimo

Answer (score 1):

> estos los tengo que ordenar de mayor a menor.

### Hacer tu propio evaluador de fracciones

Para esto deberías de convertir el numerador y denominador, ambos a tipo `"number"`. Seguidamente dividir ambos números.

```
const parseFrac = (frac) => {
    let a = parseFloat(frac.split("/")[0]);
    let b = parseFloat(frac.split("/")[1]);

    return a / b;
};
```

Aquí se convierten los dos elementos que son resultado de [`.split("/")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) a números flotantes, la función retorna el resultado de la división de estos.

Sin embargo esto va a fallar con elementos que no sean fracciones, o bien no tengan `"/"`.Tendrías que evaluar la notación de cada elemento del array. Eso se puede hacer en la misma función, pero considero que es mejor separar dos evaluaciones en dos funciones distintas.

```js
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/ 4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 6"]; 

const parseFrac = (frac) => {
    let a = parseFloat(frac.split("/")[0]);
    let b = parseFloat(frac.split("/")[1]);

    return a / b;
};

const evalNotation = (notation) => {
    evaluation = notation.includes("/") ? parseFrac(notation) : parseFloat(notation);
    return evaluation;
};


sorted = test.sort((a,b) => evalNotation(b) - evalNotation(a));
console.log(sorted);
```

Esto va a devolver un array, con los **strings originales** ordenados de mayor a menor por su valor numérico.

Si quieres obtener un array con los valores numéricos de los strings vas a tener que primero evaluar la notación de cada elemento y **después ordenarlos.**

```js
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/ 4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 6"]; 

const parseFrac = (frac) => {
    let a = parseFloat(frac.split("/")[0]);
    let b = parseFloat(frac.split("/")[1]);

    return a / b;
};

const evalNotation = (notation) => {
    evaluation = notation.includes("/") ? parseFrac(notation) : parseFloat(notation);
    return evaluation;
};


converted = test.map((n) => evalNotation(n));
sorted = converted.sort((a,b) => b - a);
console.log(sorted);
```

### Evaluaciones peligrosas

Una opción más corta es hacer uso de [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval), pero esta no es recomendada. Siempre hay que tratar de evitarla, debido a que facilita la inyección de código malicioso. La función `eval()` evalúa el string que usa como parámetro como código interpretable. Esto puede servir tanto para bien como para mal, al final de cuentas **ejecuta cualquier código interpretable por JavaScript.**

Si quieres obtener un nuevo array con los valores numéricos ordenados, puedes evaluar cada elemento (incluidas las fracciones) con `eval()` y hasta después ordenarlos.

```js
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/ 4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 6"]; 

converted = test.map((n) => eval(n));
sorted = converted.sort((a,b) => b - a);
console.log(sorted);
```

Por otro lado, si deseas obtener un array con los string originales ordenados por su valor numérico de mayor a menor, `eval()` no sería tan peligroso. Ya que se estaría usando como método de ordenamiento. De cualquier modo, siempre lo mejor es evitar el uso de `eval()`.

```js
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/ 4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 6"]; 

sorted = test.sort((a,b) => eval(b) - eval(a));
console.log(sorted);
```

Aclarar que aquí no se está usando `eval()` para evaluar cada elemento, **si no como manera de ordenar los elementos.**

> intente hacer esto:

```
test.sort((a, b) => eval(`${a} - ${b}`));
```

Realmente esto es válido, si se quisiera ordenar de menor a mayor (sin tomar en cuenta el uso de `eval()`). Si se cambia `a` por `b` si funcionaría

```
test.sort((a, b) => eval(`${b} - ${a}`));
```

La razón de esto es por la manera en que funciona [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort).

> > - Si `compareFunction(a, b)` es menor que 0, se sitúa a en un indice menor que `b`. Es decir, `a` viene primero.
>
> > - Si `compareFunction(a, b)` retorna 0, se deja `a` y `b` sin cambios entre ellos, pero ordenados con respecto a todos los elementos diferentes. *Nota: el estándar ECMAscript no garantiza este comportamiento, por esto no todos los navegadores (p.ej.  Mozilla en versiones que datan hasta el 2003) respetan esto.*
>
> > - Si `compareFunction(a, b)` es mayor que 0, se sitúa `b` en un indice menor que `a`.
>
> > - `compareFunction(a, b)` siempre debe retornar el mismo valor dado un par especifico de elementos `a` y `b` como sus argumentos. Si se retornan resultados inconsistentes entonces el orden de ordenamiento es indefinido.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Prodías intentar lo siguiente:

Utilizas una función de ayuda que te facilite la conversión del formato que tienes en el número a un decimal. En el ejemplo que te propongo con un split se separa la parte entera de la parte decimal, si existe, finalmente con un reduce se recorre el arreglo que genera el split para acumular la suma de la evaluación de la parte **entera** y la parte **decimal**

Con eso lo que queda es utilizar esta función de ayuda dentro de tu función de sort para hacer la comparación, si quieres obtener el arreglo ordenado de mayor a menor restas `b - a` o de menor a mayor restas `a - b`.

Y ya con eso obtienes lo que necesitas:

```js
const test = ["1/2", "3/4", "1", "1.1/ 4", "1.1/2", "2", "2.1/2", "3", "6", "4"];

function toDecimal(number) {
    return number
        .split('.')
        .reduce((prev, curr) => eval(prev) + eval(curr), 0);
}

test.sort((a, b) => {
    return toDecimal(b) - toDecimal(a);
})

console.log(test);
```

---

**¿Por qué no funciona tu código?**

Porque estás intentando evaluar directamente algo que no viene en una sintaxis o formato esperado por Javascript, en este caso es incomprensible la evaluación de la forma `<entero>.<numero>/<numero>` por eso es necesario crear una función que genere una versión que si pueda entender Javascript para evaluar.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciona! ahora tratare de enterderlo porque tengo muchas dudas, jamas se me hubiera ocurrido esta manera ! de verdad muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Aquí cuál criterio de mayor a menor se está siguiendo? No entiendo como 1.1 entre cuatro es mayor a 1.

Comment: No solo hay un problema en el ordenamiento, sino que veo que utilizas [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval), cosa que no es recomendado a menos que estemos totalmente seguros de que los datos a evaluar están bajo nuestro total y absoluto control. En conclusión, debemos [evitar en lo posible](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval#No_utilice_eval_innecesariamente) usar la función `eval()`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Parece que no han entendido la representación numérica que se está haciendo acá. Cuando ves un `1.1/4` esto hace referencia a "Un entero, un cuarto" lo cual es igual a 1.25, esto no es "Uno punto uno dividido entre cuatro"

Comment: @MediEle Ya que mi respuesta sí parece ser lo que buscas, podrías aclarar a los demás qué es lo que necesitas, en caso de ser así te agradecería que la votases como correcta.

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza, menuda notación de fracciones mixtas. Habrá que esperar que el OP aclare la duda. Eso de meter un punto para separar el entero de la fracción es como dicen en mi tierra: *una conchita de mango*. Usualmente uno espera una fracción mixta que use como separador un simple espacio, por ejemplo: `"3 2/3"`. En fin, que el OP no lo puso claro en su pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @DanielRodriguezMeza 1.1 entre 4 se aproxima a 0.25, no veo como llegaste a 1.25.

Comment: Hola @DanielRodríguezMeza pasa que estos numeros son medidas de valvulas, por eso necesitaba ordernarlas para mostrarlas en forma dinamica al cliente. le di al boton responde la pregunta

Comment: @MediEle Nop, aún no has marcado una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo:

```js
 let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 3/8", " 1/4"];
        //Funcion que realiza la ecuación division para obtener un resultado que ordenar, en caso que que no haya division devuelve el entero ejemplo 2.
        function ecuacion(v) {
            return v.split("/").reduce(function (a, b) {
                return parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(b);
            });
        }
        //Funcion array sort para ordenar utilizando el resultado de la ecuacion.
        test.sort(function (a, b) {
            return ecuacion(b)-ecuacion(a);
        });
        
        
        console.log(test);
```